# What effect does running multiple Databricks scheduled jobs have on the performance of the cluster they are running on?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, databricks-workflows

My doubt is whether having multiple notebooks scheduled to run at the same time will in any way affect the overall performance of any given notebook scheduled job?
Additionally, would there also be any effect on the overall performance of the cluster whilst running these multiple scheduled jobs?

So far I have about 20 scheduled jobs taking 1 - 3 minutes each which are all scheduled to run at the same time.
However, this number will increase drastically in the coming months and it would be good to know preemptively whether this will affect the cluster's performance. If so, would scheduling these jobs for different times help ameliorate the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It will have a performance effect if you're running all these jobs on the same interactive cluster.  But it's a bad practice anyway, so it's recommended to run them on individual job clusters - that could be cheaper. If you're concerned about startup time, then look onto [instance pools](https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/pool-best-practices.html), and run jobs with some offsets against each other.

Comment: I'm aware that we can use instance pools with job clusters via ADF. Is there a way to use instance pools with job cluster as part of workflows ?

Comment: yes, of course...